# Porting code that compares 32bit floats to use 64bit, what does this value represent?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I'm porting some code that compares floating point numbers to handle 64bit doubles instead of 32bit floats but i'm a little confused by some magic numbers used in the code.

Source: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Here's the code:

```
bool AlmostEqual2sComplement(float A, float B, int maxUlps)
{
    // Make sure maxUlps is non-negative and small enough that the
    // default NAN won't compare as equal to anything.
    assert(maxUlps > 0 && maxUlps < 4 * 1024 * 1024);
    int aInt = *(int*)&A;
    // Make aInt lexicographically ordered as a twos-complement int
    if (aInt < 0)
        aInt = 0x80000000 - aInt;
    // Make bInt lexicographically ordered as a twos-complement int
    int bInt = *(int*)&B;
    if (bInt < 0)
        bInt = 0x80000000 - bInt;
    int intDiff = abs(aInt - bInt);
    if (intDiff <= maxUlps)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

**Questions:**

The main thing that stumps me is the `4 * 1024 * 1024` number in the assert. What does this represent and what would the this value be for 64bit doubles? Would it be the same for both?

Also the `0x80000000` magic number is used as a int representation of a negative zero float. So i'm guessing for 64bit doubles this would have to increase to `0x8000000000000000`?

Answer (score 2):

Ewww.

4 * 1024 * 1024 is 22 bits, which is one less than the number of explicit mantissa bits for a float. The equivalent for double would be 2**51, I think.

You're right about the 0x800... This code is relying on the fact that IEEE floating point numbers can be compared as if they were integers represented using sign and magnitude, mostly.

This code is horribly full of undefined behaviour, of course. Not to mention nasty, brutish and short.

Comment: Does `2**51 == 0x8000000000000`? Also i'm not a big C++ fan i'm porting it to D where this undefined behaviour nonsense doesn't exist. :)

Comment: Dunno, lost count after the 7th 0. Reinterpreting a `double` as an `int` is bad news even if you fix the endianness and require IEEE754.

Comment: I'm not reinterpreting a double as an int.

Comment: Yes you are - that's what `*(int*)&A` does, and what this whole function depends on. (Assuming you have changed float to double as you said.)